# Answer with outdated links

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, hyperlinks, link-rot

I have a question regarding outdated links in answers.

While browsing through Stack Overflow, I stumbled upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891312/froyo-android-2-2-source-code/2891799#2891799) that was finally answered by giving the right [hyperlink](http://android.git.kernel.org/). Unfortunately, this link is now outdated and so the answer is no longer helpful. Consequently I raised a flag and wrote a comment accordingly (actually it's even the third one with outdated links that I saw).

What I wonder is, how is the Stack Overflow community taking care, that these kind of outdated answers get updated or removed? What is the best way to handle these posts, so that a clean up process can start?

Comment: Usually we take care of this by not allowing link-only answers (or questions that invite them), just to prevent situations like these. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A suggested edit would be the right course of action - one that provides the correct link instead of the obsolete one. With the edit comment explaining the issue.

If you have enough reputation to edit directly, that's the correct course of action.

Flagging is not really suitable here, unless you can't suggest an edit (and even anonymous users can) - such is the case ff there is absolutely no alternative link, as bluefeet [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173133/answer-with-outdated-links/173134?noredirect=1#comment514508_173134), then a comment and flag to that effect would be OK, to allow removal of the answer by moderators.

This is why we don't like link only answers - a dead link makes it useless.

Comment: But shouldn't you flag it if the link is dead and there is no alternative? That pretty much makes the answer useless if the link is dead and the user did not provide any context.

Comment: @bluefeet - my assumption was that there _was_ an alternative.

Comment: I'm sure there will often be an alternative - not at least due to some kind of *waybackmaschine* (e.g. http://archive.org/index.php). Though in fact both cases might happen ...

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the clarification. :)