# Link to answer with proper link text

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

I have noticed some inconsistency when linking to an answer

`https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257371`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257371

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/can-i-fetch-a-stash-from-a-remote-repo-into-a-local-branch/5257371#5257371`
[Can I fetch a stash from a remote repo into a local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/can-i-fetch-a-stash-from-a-remote-repo-into-a-local-branch/5257371#5257371)

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/5257371#5257371`
[Can I fetch a stash from a remote repo into a local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/5257371#5257371)

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/#5257371`
[Can I fetch a stash from a remote repo into a local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680/#5257371)

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680#5257371`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248680#5257371

As you can see, all the above links point to the same post, but only some of them are translated to the actual post name. This seem to be an inconsistency - shouldn't all the supported formats get the automatic translation?

Comment: The front controller is too flexible for you? You would rather we should serve more error pages, maybe?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I would rather it make sense. [Don’t Make Me Think](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Make_Me_Think)

Comment: The same here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173133/191655 vs http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173134/191655

Comment: Steven, I edited the question to make it more clear since somebody seem to have voted to close it as "Unclear what you are asking". *I don't really think it  was unclear to begin with but...* I hope it will help.